# Permutation Leetcode

Tags: python, permutation

I was solving this leetcode permutation problem and came across an error that am getting n empty lists inside my returned list which suppose to print different permutations of the given list

getting output => `[[], [], [], [], [], []]`

Expected output=> `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]`

```
def permute(nums):
    l=[]
    s=list()
    ans=[]

        return helper(nums,s,l)
def helper(nums,s,l):
    if not nums:
        print(l)
        s.append(l)
    else:
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            c=nums[i]
            l.append(c)
            nums.pop(i)
            helper(nums,s,l)
            nums.insert(i,c)
            l.pop()
    return s
print(permute([1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do `s.append(l.copy())` because otherwise you pop all values from the same list `l`, that's why the result consists of empty lists.

Comment: can you edit the code so that i could get the desired answer as am getting this  [<function list.copy()>,
 <function list.copy()>,
 <function list.copy()>,
 <function list.copy()>,
 <function list.copy()>,
 <function list.copy()>]

Comment: @yolonbsn please check if you write exactly `s.append(l.copy())`, not `s.append(l.copy)` - note the parentheses.

Comment: can you please tell me how the l is getting empty why did we used copy()

Comment: @yolonbsn it is getting empty because of two factors: 1) the list `l` is always the same in every call to `helper` function - it is passed by reference. 2) there is a line `l.pop()` to every line `l.append(...)` so in the end the number of calls to `pop` and `append` equals. To avoid this problem we use `copy` at the moment we need the value of `l` to be unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `s.append(l[:])` this slicing also does the same

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).